# Xdebug Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'Request failed with status code 400'

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to setup Xdebug with PhpStorm. When I try and validate my script, I get the following error:

> Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'Request failed with status code 400'

The error used to display a 404 status code, but I applied the fix on this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/validating-the-configuration-of-the-debugging-engine.html#troubleshooting-validation-results

I haven't seen anything online for fixing a 400 status code.

I have the site setup on a local environment using nginx and an upstream using php-fpm.sock.

```
upstream site_backend {
   server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

And here is my xdebug.ini:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                    /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini                                              
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

The site works, only Xdebug isn't working. PhpStorm is not registering anything from Xdebug.

Not sure what else is needed, let me know if you need anything else.

UPDATE:

Xdebug is version 3.0.4.

In the nginx error log, I saw something that might be helpful:

```
2021/04/19 10:26:08 [error] 736434#736434: *72 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mysite.localhost, request: "GET /_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.localhost"
```

UPDATE 2:
I made the changes at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide, still isn't working. Here is the update xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.session=PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Not sure if it's correct configuration. I also double checked to make sure PHPStorm is listening on port 9003, which it is. I also restarted php-fpm as well.

Comment: What is your Xdebug version?

Comment: What is in your php-fpm/webserver's error log? Which Xdebug version are you using, as your settings are for the outdated Xdebug 2, and won't work with Xdebug 3 (see the upgrade guide: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: `zend_extension=xdebug.so` is not valid, you must be set the absolute file path!

Comment: @EricBrown 1) See the link that Derick gave and update your Xdebug config. 2) The Validation in PhpStorm: it just check some common params. It is pure optional step.

Comment: @AdamP. Not true. At least since PHP 7.2. I just have `zend_extension=xdebug` and it works (Windows 10 if that makes any diff here)

Comment: It still isn't working for me. I have updated my question.

Comment: That latter looks like to be just a Nginx configuration issue? It seems to deny the request for that URL. I would just put PhpStorm in listen mode, and request a PHP script with `xdebug_info();` in it, which should tell you what Xdebug is trying to do, and what its version is, and which modes are enabled. Your config looks good.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I removed, then reinstalled the php7.4-xdebug package. It's working now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and I was able to resolve this buy just replacing the default URL assigned (http://127.0.0.1) with my virtual host URL in PHPStorm > Run > Web Server Debug Validation > URL to validation script.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

PHP version: 7.4.3

XDebug version: 2.9.2

/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 #if you want to change the port you can change
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I resolved this buy just
changing the value in the php.ini file of the xdebug.start_upon_error from the default "default" to "yes" due too https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#configuring-xdebug-docker

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue by using ddev ( = a docker wrapper).
The absolute path to my project is `/var/www/html` in ddev.
I had to write `/var/www/html` as the absolute path to my project in the phpstorm settings at `php>servers`.